# Protocol and Delegate between View and Controller

Tags: objective-c, protocols

I'm having some trouble getting the protocol/delegate method to work between the Model (GraphView) and the Controller (GraphViewController). The NSLog in the *drawRect:* in GraphView.m tells me that *expression* is *null*

the variable *expression* holds a value (the NSLog in ViewDidLoad proves this). Am I missing something obvious?

**GraphView.h**

```
@class GraphView;

@protocol GraphViewDelegate
-(NSString *) expressionForGraphView:(GraphView *) requestor; 
@end

@interface GraphView : UIView
{
      id <GraphViewDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (assign) id <GraphViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**GraphView.m**

```
#import "GraphView.h"

@implementation GraphView

@synthesize delegate;

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
      NSString *expression = [self.delegate expressionForGraphView:self];
      NSLog(@"%@", expression);

}
```

**GraphViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GraphView.h"

@interface GraphViewController : UIViewController <GraphViewDelegate>
{
    GraphView *graphView;
    NSString *expression;
}

@property (retain) IBOutlet GraphView *graphView;
@property (retain) NSString *expression;

@end
```

**GraphViewController.m**

```
#import "GraphViewController.h"

@implementation GraphViewController

@synthesize graphView;
@synthesize expression;

-(NSString *) expressionForGraphView:(GraphView *) requestor
{
      NSString *tempString;
      if (requestor == self.graphView)
        tempString = self.expression;
      else 
        tempString = nil;

      return tempString;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.graphView.delegate = self;
     NSLog(@"%@", self.expression);
}
```

Comment: Have you placed any NSLogs in `expressionForGraphView:` to see why **`tempString`** is returning `nil`?

Comment: In what order are your log statements happening? (You'll probably need to add more text to them to tell.)

Comment: The ViewController gets called first, so on ViewDidLoad I can see that expression has a value - no problems there. However when GraphView drawRect is called the NSLog is null. For info the graphView object has its 'setNeedsDisplay' method called by the ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the method name

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

The view has already loaded before you set the delegate. Therefore when the `drawRect` was called the delegate was `nil`.

Set up the delegate in the relevant initializer method or in IB